# row index of DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and on a Click I want to find index of a clicked cell. I found a way to get `DataGridCell`, and `DataGridCellInfo`, but there is only column index in it.

How to get row index? I cannot find a way to get it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found an answer! For the future people who will look for it:

```
DataGridRow r2 = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(cell);
int rowindex = r2.GetIndex();
```